# BST graphical representation needed in java

Tags: java, swing, javafx, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I am using [Model–view–controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) design pattern, I need a UI Viewer for my BST/AVL models ,**I already developed the Model and controller logics, I just need the viewer**,  I do not need to deal with graphics right now, it would be useful if someone has a **Viewer** class with a method that takes the root of a tree and draws it, no need for advanced animation or effects

something like

```
SimpleBSTreeViewer.draw(myTree.getRoot());
```

node structure of the tree

```
public class NodeBST <T extends Comparable<T>> {
 private T data;
 private NodeBST<T> left;
 private NodeBST<T> right;
 private NodeBST<T> parent;
 
 //other methods go here ...
}
```

this would be helpful to focus of coding the logic part,

I have searched and found other java applets that represents trees but they have the model-logic and view in same class , I  am working in model-view-controller pattern (MVC pattern) , it is better to separate model from view as much as possible , I just want a viewer for my model

-Note: this is a sample of what i need (I already use JTree and it is not satisfactory.)

[image]

Comment: JGraph is quite easy to use. http://www.jgraph.com/
Or you can just use JTree.

Comment: You can build the viewer easily yourself using http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html and http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/TreeView.html.

Comment: If you are having trouble coding the logic, a debugger would do as good as a display of your tree.

Comment: I updated question, is that more clear now ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Get [Jgraphx](https://github.com/jgraph/jgraphx) library and starting from `HelloWorld` in the
  examples I coded this class
- Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184655/set-position-for-drawing-binary-tree) question to calculate coordinates of the nodes.

  ```
  package algorithms.searching.bst;

  import java.util.Random;

  import javax.swing.JFrame;

  import log.Logger;

  import algorithms.searching.bst.avl.AVL;

  import com.mxgraph.swing.mxGraphComponent;
  import com.mxgraph.view.mxGraph;

  @SuppressWarnings("serial")

  public class TreeViewer<T extends Comparable<T>> extends JFrame {

  static private int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 600;
  static private int CANVAS_WIDTH = 1000;

  private int rootY = 10;
  private int NODE_SIZE = 25;
  private int ROW_HEIGHT = 50;
  mxGraph graph = new mxGraph();
  Object parent = graph.getDefaultParent();

  /**
   * draws a tree starting from this root
   * 
   * @param root
   * @param depth
   *            number of nodes to the root (including root)
   * @param index
   *            index of node in this level (leftChildIndex = parentIndex * 2
   *            - 1) and (rightChildIndex = parentIndex * 2)
   * @return
   */
  public Object drawTree(NodeBST<T> root, int depth, int index) {
      if (root == null) {
          return null;
      }

      // draw root

      /*
       * leftChildIndex = parentIndex * 2 - 1 
       * rightChildIndex = parentIndex *2
       *
       *
       * x = index * canvasWidth / (2^depth + 1)
       *
       * y = depth * canvasHeight / treeDepth
       */

      int myX = (int) ((CANVAS_WIDTH * (index)) / (Math.pow(2, depth - 1) + 1));

      Object rootVertex = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, root.getData(),
              myX, depth * ROW_HEIGHT + rootY, NODE_SIZE, NODE_SIZE);

      Logger.log("new x coordinate=" + myX);

      // recurse for right child

      Object rightChildVertex = drawTree(root.getRight(), depth + 1,
              index * 2);

      if (rightChildVertex != null) {// edge
          graph.insertEdge(parent, null, "R", rootVertex, rightChildVertex,
                  "startArrow=none;endArrow=none;strokeWidth=1;strokeColor=green");
      }

      Object leftChildVertex = drawTree(root.getLeft(), depth + 1,
              index * 2 - 1);

      // recurse for right child

      if (leftChildVertex != null) { // edge
          graph.insertEdge(parent, null, "L", rootVertex, leftChildVertex,
                  "startArrow=none;endArrow=none;strokeWidth=1;strokeColor=green");
      }

      return rootVertex;

  }

  /**
   * Redraw the whole tree
   * 
   * @param root
   *            the root of tree to be drawn
   */

  public void update(NodeBST<T> root) {

      graph.getModel().beginUpdate();

      try {

          Object[] cells = graph.getChildCells(parent, true, false);
          graph.removeCells(cells, true);
          drawTree(root, 1, 1);

      } finally {
          graph.getModel().endUpdate();
      }
  }

  public TreeViewer(NodeBST<T> root) {
      // super("Hello, World!");

      this.update(root);

      mxGraphComponent graphComponent = new mxGraphComponent(graph);

      getContentPane().add(graphComponent);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      AVL<Integer> bst = new AVL<Integer>();//use AVL tree class 

      Random randomGenerator = new Random();
      for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {//try generating 20 random integers
          bst.insert(randomGenerator.nextInt(1000));
      }

      TreeViewer<Integer> myTreeViewer=new TreeViewer<Integer>(bst.getRoot());
      JFrame frame = myTreeViewer;

      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setSize(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
      frame.setVisible(true);

  }



  }
  ```
- simply modify this class to take your tree class
- Thank you very much  [NeplatnyUdaj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2266098/neplatnyudaj) !

[image: Viewing AVL tree]

Comment: updated version of TreeViewer in my repository [here](https://github.com/Amr1977/Assignments/blob/master/algorithms/searching/bst/TreeViewer.java)